# Adding together curves or shapes to approximate something more complex

Tags: geometry, reference-request, functions, soft-question, terminology

I'm looking for proper terminology / references for the following sort of problem:

Say we have some one-dimensional curve like $y = 10$ defined over the real valued domain $[0,1]$, and we ask, how can we best approximate this curve by aligning and summing a fixed set of one or more component curves (that we have no control over)?  In this case, perhaps a component curve could be $y = 1$ over some domain $[A,B]$ where $B-A=0.5$.  So we'd simply set $A=0$ and $B=0.1$, and then sum ten of these together, then set $A=0.5$ and $B=1$ and sum ten of these curves together, and we'd have our $y = 10$ curve over the domain $[0,1]$.  A more complicated example might ask how one would align and sum multiple smaller curves to approximate some concave shape, where perhaps this can only be done imperfectly.

I'm interested in this sort of problem in two- and three-dimensions (with two-dimensional curves).  Where in mathematics does this sort of problem arise, and what are some "magic words" that would help me find references?  It feels like this might loosely be related to Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Fourier analysis is similar to this, because there, we approximate a function as a sum of sines and cosines (complex powers of $e$). This is also done with Taylor polynomials, where you approximate a function with a sum of powers of $x$. This can be done because the set of functions $e^{fx}$ forms a basis of the set of all functions (also non-differentiable functions, but I'm not sure about continuous functions). All infinite polynomials of $x$ also form a basis of the 'nice' functions.

To apply a similar technique to your situation, you have to be sure there exists a linear combination of 'base' functions that equals your 'target' function. Then, try to write the basis in a general form and try to apply similar methods as in Fourier analysis (thus, to determine the coefficient of $b$ in $f$ integrate $f(x)b(x)$ over the domain with $f$ the target and $b$ the base function).